# Graph or Relational DB specifically recursion

Tags: recursion, neo4j, relational-database, graph-databases

I am about to develop a solution for a customer where the basic entity is a member and members can have different multiple social relationships with other members. For instance Lets say we have four types of members Doctors, Specialist, Nurses and Patients. So one or more Doctors can consult one or more Specialists, One or more Doctors can treat one or more Patients. One or more Doctor is in Charge of one or more Nurses. So if I were to use a Relational DB a high degree of recursion would be necessary (as All entities must be members).  Whereas recursion is not necessary in a Graph data model.

Is it then safe to say it is better to use a Graph database for a social type application where members may have different or overlapping roles.

Comment: I see no need for recursion in there. Recursion would be Doctors consulting Doctors.

Comment: Doctors, Specialist, Nurses and Patients are all Members and a Doctor could also be a patient and consult other doctors, as well as one or more Doctors is in charge of one or more doctors.

Comment: Dug yourself a big hole with sharp pointy sticks in it, and then jumped in from 500 feet, carrying 500 lbs. A doctor who is patient is not a doctor as far as the relationship with their Doctor is concerned.

Comment: I agree, however their role as doctor does exist as such as a member it cannot be ignored.

Comment: Only because you are specifying relationships between members instead of Doctors and Patients. Listen to the Doctor, prevention is better than cure. :)

Comment: Just to clarify Doctor. Are you saying the I should have independent tables for each member type? I am thinking in terms of roles.

Comment: Probably... I'm talking abstract out Say Person. A Doctor is Person, A Patient is a Person. DoctorPatient is a particular relationship between two People. Whether it would be useful to Have a DoctorPatient Table or a Relationsship of Type DoctorPatient isn't clear though. Either way has it's pros and cons. It's the way I'd be looking if Relational data base was the choice and it's not recursive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A graph database would be good at modelling these kinds of relationships.  There's a few ways that you might model it.  You could think of a vertex as being a Member with different edges from Member to other Members representing the types of relationships:

- Member --consults--> Member (physician to specialist)
- Member --reportsTo--> Member (nurse to physician)
- Member --diagnoses--> Member (physician to patient)

Obviously a Member may have as many of any edge type (e.g. multiple "consults" with specialists). In a more complex model, you might also see a Member as being an "identity" for a person such that your model looks like:

- Member --actsAsPhysician--> Physician
- Member --actsAsSpecialist--> Specialist
- Physician --consults--> Specialist

In this approach the "consults" edge can only exist on a "Physician" vertex, thus you provide some constraints as to what vertex types can be expected to have what kind of edges.

Graphs provide you a lot of flexibility in being able to model data such as it exists in the real-world as you are really just describing entities and the relationships among them.      I'd encourage you to look at http://tinkerpop.com for a collection of tools that are helpful in building graph applications independent of the graph database you choose.

Answer (score -1):

If every one is a member then member is central to the data model in a relational perspective. There is no need for recursive SQL select statements:

Member ->---<- Doctor ->---<- Patients
One or More Members is One or More Doctors One or More Doctors treats One or More Patients

Your model will have a lot of Many to Many relationships and alot of Relationship tables. For instance the Treats relation could contain attributes such as Treatment Period
Ailment
etc.

Your solution could be implemented in any topology. While the network/graph topology is faster than the Set topology the graph data model once implemented is almost impossible to change. History tells us it is unwise to build rigid business applications. So research the pros and cons of each and make a decision.