# Refactoring a NoSql Database Schema

Tags: mongodb, neo4j, nosql

I am considering Nosql for a project we are about to start (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20588134/1838739). In regard to modifying NoSql i am confused about this statement "While the network/graph topology is faster than the Set topology the graph data model once implemented is almost impossible to change." Is this true for Nosql? How flexible is it to modify if changes are needed in a production implemented db.

Answer (score 1):

Graph database are very open for change since the relationships are part of the data and not part of a schema.

To get started I recommend to read a little bit on Cypher (http://www.neo4j.org/learn/cypher or http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/cypher-query-lang.html). You'll see quickly how easy graphs can be changed.